# Merge multiple Raster MBTiles (Sqlite file) through commandline

Tags: sqlite, mbtiles

I have 50 `mbtiles` files which is in Raster format. `mbtiles` file is basically an `SQLite` file. I have successfully merged them through SQLite IDE using the following query.

```
ATTACH 'path/to/db2.mbtiles' AS db2;
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO map SELECT * from db2.map;
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO images SELECT * from db2.images;
```

But I am trying to do it using a shell script. Here what I am doing in my commandline. At first, I am opening an SQLite database using the `sqlite3 01.mbtiles;` command. It is opening the database but in the schema, there is no `image` and `map` table.

[image]

When I am attaching another SQLite DB using `attach 02.mbties as db2;` it is most probably attaching as there is no shell output. After that when I am trying to merge data using

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO map SELECT * from db2.map;
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO images SELECT * from db2.images;
```

It is returning

```
Error: no such table: map
Error: no such table: images
```

Can it be merged using commandline?

Comment: It seams `02.mbties` doesn't have `map` neither `images` tables. Have you checked?

Comment: You are missing `'` in filename: `attach '02.mbties' as db2;` Your error output must be disabled.

Comment: File path: if `attach` doesn't find database in current path, it will assume a new database. That should be your issue.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ I can attach and merge them through SQLite Manager. So there are Map and Image tables.

Comment: I am not finding `map` & `image` table in the first DB also so the attachment of `'` is not an issue

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ I am provoding the right path that is why other tables are showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221857/discussion-between-ls--and-devils-dream).